# Ldap error on a Windows10 Client; Apache 2.4 and PHP 7.2.12

Tags: windows-10, apache-http-server, php

I try to activate the extension ldap on my php7 installation. When i startup the Apache 2.4 Server, I get the following error:

```
php_ldap.dll (The specified module could not be found.)
```

On the net I found some ideas with libsasl.dll, libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll. In PHP7 only libsasl.dll is included. So i guess, PHP have done some changes between PHP5 and PHP7.

How can I run ldap on Windows?

Comment: Did you check the [official documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.ldap.php)? What does this have to do with PHP5?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. The problem was, that in the environment variables in the path, php7 wasn't a path, so he doesn't found the dll's